# VBA for Raiser's Edge CRM Database

Tags: vba

I am trying to strip the last character off of a field in Raiser's Edge.

The code I currently have is:

```
Option Explicit



    Sub Test()
Dim oRec As CRecord
Set oRec = New CRecord
oRec.Init REApplication.SessionContext
 oRec.Load (2)

 oRec.Fields(RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME) = Left(oRec, Len(oRec.Fields.RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME) - 1)
oRec.Save
Set oRec = Nothing
oRec.Closedown
End Sub
```

I'm trying to turn "Mary1" into "Mary" and load the new string - Mary - back into the last name field. This is giving the general syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, couple of things here:

- You'll probably want to set scope on your procedure to be either Public or Private (optional).
- You cannot access a field value by using "Fields.VALUE". Fields is a property, so you must pass in the field identifier as a parameter, like this:

  ```
  sName = oRec.Fields(RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME)
  ```
- When you say "Left(oRec, ...", you are trying to get the left characters on oRec rather than the last name field of oRec. You need to do this instead:

  ```
  Left(oRec.Fields(RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME), ...
  ```
- You must call .CloseDown *before* you set oRec = Nothing.

Here is the corrected code:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim oRec As CRecord
    Set oRec = New CRecord
    oRec.Init REApplication.SessionContext
    oRec.Load (27993)
    oRec.Fields(RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME) = Left(oRec.Fields(RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME), Len(oRec.Fields(RECORDS_fld_LAST_NAME)) - 1)
    oRec.Save
    oRec.Closedown
    Set oRec = Nothing
End Sub
```

On a side note, keep in mind that [ImportOmatic for the Raiser's Edge](http://www.omaticsoftware.com/Solutions/TheRaisersEdge/ImportOmatic.aspx) has a built-in API that can frequently be used for data manipulations like this before your data even reaches RE.  :)

Comment: Thanks so much, Monty! I have importomatic but the flawed data is already in RE, from a system conversion done years ago.